# Keybindings "value is not accepted" (after the 1.40 update)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have several entries in my `keybindings.json` file. Yesterday, shortly after updating to the October VSCode release, I tried adding a few new keybindings through the "Keyboard shortcuts" widget via the Command Palette, but encountered the following error:

[image]

I checked for errors in my `keybindings.json` file (full copy [here](https://gist.github.com/amelio-vazquez-reina/1ab8ea2ce3ad1b4c33deb53ea76b622c)), and all I have are entries like the one below.

[image]

What's strange about this:

- I only have warnings, yet VSCode complains about errors
- All of these errors are tied to `emacs-mcx` from [this extension](https://github.com/tuttieee/vscode-emacs-mcx) (for reference I opened an issue with them [here](https://github.com/tuttieee/vscode-emacs-mcx/issues/144) just in case)

With this in mind:

1. How does VSCode check for values that it can accept? (the warning says "Value is not accepted")
2. Can I tell VSCode to ignore those problematic entries? (there is no syntax error per se)
3. If all I have are warnings, why does VSCode complain about errors in the file?

Comment: I have the same problem, since the v1.40 update.  Warnings from a macro extension, which works fine, but now I get the same error notification and vscode can't write into keybindings.json - as when trying to remove a built-in keybinding from the Keyboard Shortcuts list.  I had to temporarily those three warning keybindings I had and then re-enable them.  Should be a github issue I think.

Comment: Thanks @Mark I just created an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84436)

Comment: I added my use case to your issue.

Comment: Looks like it is fixed in the Insiders' Build as of today.  As a bonus, it got rid of my warnings too - about `Value is not accepted.`!!

Comment: Yes - thanks @Mark! I also tried that today - Thanks for helping with and sharing your knowledge with this issue .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was apparently a bug that VSCode resolved [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84436) after I created an issue tied to this question (coming out in the October recovery release)

> This is because the parser needs option allowTrailingComma to be set to true. It was default to true before.
>
> @aeschli Looks like this was added in last milestone and not adopted
> in keybindings service.

Patch [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/ce9f8e1c94fe768d555bd57061942ddc86cda944)